# Downsampling the Kinect 2's Color Camera input

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

*I'm using the Kinect 2 for Windows and the C# version of the SDK. If needed writing a separate C++ lib or using C#'s unsafe regions for better performance is definitely an option*

I'm trying to downsample the input of the Kinect's Color Camera as 1920x1080 pixels @ 30 fps is a bit much.  But I cannot find a built in function to reduce the resolution (very odd, am I missing something?)

My next idea was to store the data in a large byte[] and then selectively sample from that byte[] directly into another byte[] to reduce the amount of data.

```
    int ratio = full.Length / smallBuffer.Length;

    int bpp = (int)frameDescription.BytesPerPixel;

    for (int i = 0; i < small.Length; i += bpp)
    {                
        Array.Copy(full, i * ratio, small, i, bpp);
    }
```

However, this method gives me a very funny result. The image has the correct width and height but the image is repeated along the horizontal axis multiple times. (Twice if I use half the original resoltion, thrice if I use a third, etc...).

How can I correctly downsample (subsample is actually a better description) the video?

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was letting the encoder (x264VFW in my case do the downsampling, the real bottleneck turned out to be the copying of the array which was solved by giving the encoder a pointer to where the array was in managed memory (using a `GCHandle`).